# WPF Simple Commanding Example

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try not to post questions like this, but i've really been struggling to find an answer or similar example. I have what I think is a really simple example I'd like to setup.
Basically I want to use commanding to add an item from a textbox to a listbox. I want to make sure there is something in the textbox via CanExecute and i want to make sure that its not already in the list.

I know this seems over complicated for what it is, but it hits on some points I've been struggling with.

[image: Simple interface]

```
<Window x:Class="Commanding_Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:Commanding_Example"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="200" Height="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <Button>Add</Button>
        <Button>Remove</Button>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I have a Person Class

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The only reason I have this is that the Add needs to create a new object, so slightly more complex than a simple string.

And then a basic view model

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add( new Person {Name = "jimmy"});
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    #region Default INotifyPropertyChanged implimentation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So the question is, how would I implement commanding so that it uses the CanExecute to disable the Add button if the name is already there or the Name field is empty.

And then the same deal for Remove, only enabled if a name is selected in the list.

I'd like to make this as MVVM compliment as possible.

I've seen that you can do the Button.CommandBindings attached property to inject the methods you'd like to use for each, but that doesnt seem completely MVVM happy.

Also, i'd like to avoid the use of frameworks (Prism/Caliburn.Micro) since this is primarily for education reasons.

Also any references would be greatly appreciated. I've read many blogs etc but I always feel like they stray off before implementing a complete, *simple* example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I implement commanding so that it uses the CanExecute to
>   disable the Add button if the name is already there or the Name field
>   is empty

I will show how to do the add, the remove is similar and I leave that for you to figure out. First I will show the xaml changes with the button using an `AddPerson` command:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPerson, 
                Mode=TwoWay, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
               }"/>
<Button Command="{Binding AddPerson}">Add</Button>
```

We have bound the current *edited* text to a new property on the View Model named `CurrentPerson`. This is done because we want to access what the person enters, but also we need the binding *updated* as the user types. To accomplish that updating, we specify that the binding updates by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` attribute to be `PropertyChanged`. Otherwise our the `CurrentPerson` string and ultimately the command `Can` operation would only fire when the edit text box lost focus.

**ViewModel**
The viewmodel will subscribe to the `AddPerson` command. Execution of that will add the user, but also check a `can` method which returns a boolean whether to enable the button or not. The can will be excecuted when the `CurrentPerson` property changes where we ultimately call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on the commanding class to have the button check the `can` method.

(*This VM is abbreviated for the example and based on your full VM*)

```
public OperationCommand AddPerson { get; set; }
public string _currentPerson;

public MainViewModel()
{
 People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
 People.Add(new Person { Name = "jimmy" });

            // First Lamda is where we execute the command to add,
            // The second lamda is the `Can` method to enable the button.
 AddPerson = new OperationCommand((o) => People.Add(new Person { Name = CurrentPerson }),
                                  (o) => (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentPerson) && 
                                          !People.Any(per => per.Name == CurrentPerson)));

 // When the edit box text changes force a `Can` check.
 this.PropertyChanged += MainViewModel_PropertyChanged ;
}

void MainViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentPerson")
        AddPerson.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Finally here is the commanding class used which is based on my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017):

```
public class OperationCommand : ICommand
{

#region Variables

Func<object, bool> canExecute;
Action<object> executeAction;

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

#endregion

#region Properties

#endregion

#region Construction/Initialization

public OperationCommand(Action<object> executeAction)
    : this(executeAction, null)
{
}

public OperationCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
{
    if (executeAction == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Execute Action was null for ICommanding Operation.");
    }
    this.executeAction = executeAction;
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
}

#endregion

#region Methods

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    bool result = true;
    Func<object, bool> canExecuteHandler = this.canExecute;
    if (canExecuteHandler != null)
    {
        result = canExecuteHandler(parameter);
    }

    return result;
}

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    EventHandler handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    this.executeAction(parameter);
}

#endregion

}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I only have one problem. Once i click Add and the new name in the list, the textbox retains the name and the Add button is enabled. I assume I need to trigger the onpropertychanged again, but im not sure where/how this would be best done. Thanks!

Comment: @jrich523 You might want to change the lamdas to method calls an wire in the logic to clear the current text and other items within those methods. To push a change to the `can` operation call `AddPerson.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` to refresh the display. Note I didn't mention it, but one can also wire up commands in the view, if one has view specific operations; so you may want to create a separate command which the main page uses to do any GUI operations which the VM should not do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, MVVM is just a pattern or philosophy, so I think your desire to avoid using a framework might be a little misguided.  Even if you're not using one of those frameworks, you will essentially be writing your own framework in order to implement the MVVM pattern.

That being said, probably what you want to use is a `DelegateCommand` or one of the similar implementations.  See: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html.  The important part that I think you are looking for is that the command that the WPF button is binding to must raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event whenever there is a change made in the view model which affects whether the command can or cannot be executed.

So in your case, for example, you would want to add a call to the `CanExecuteChanged` of your `AddPersonDelegateCommand` to your `OnPropertyChanged` method (possibly filtered by the name of the property that was changed).  This tells anything bound to the command to call `CanExecute` on the command, and then you would have your logic in that `CanExecute` that actually determines if a person with the entered name already exists.

So to add some sample code, it might look something like this:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        People.Add( new Person {Name = "jimmy"});
        AddPersonDelegateCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddPerson, CanAddPerson);
    }

  // Your existing code here

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
      if(propertyName == "NewNameTextBox") AddPersonDelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  public DelegateCommand AddPersonDelegateCommand { get; set; }

  public void AddPerson()
  { 
      // Code to add a person to the collection
  }

  public bool CanAddPerson()
  {
      return !People.Any(p=>p.Name == NewNameTextBox);
  }

  public string NewNameTextBox 
  { 
    get { return _newNameTextBox; }
    set 
    { 
       _newNameTextBox = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: In this sample your `<TextBox></TextBox>` would need to be bound to the `NewNameTextBox` property on the view model.